# Sound Block Buttons

Tags: animation, audio

Not 100% sure this is what im looking for, but does anyone know where to find the sound block buttons? (for the most recent version of blender?)

I do some animating and I want to sync mouth movements to an audio. I check audio scrubbing, so I can match a single frame to a single frame sound. But when I click on the timeline, the audio plays from that point. The animation is paused too so I can't properly animate.

I'm not sure if Sound Block Buttons is going help me, but I've been trying everything. I've googled all I can. If anyone can help me, or find another way to animate to vocals, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

I think the option you are looking for is called **Draw Waveform**.

In the *Video Sequence Editor*, press <kbd>N</kbd> to display the *Properties Toolbar*. Find the *Sound* panel (while the audio track is selected) and enable the *Draw Waveform* option.

[image: Video Sequence Editor - Draw Waveform option in the sidebar's Sound panel]